# Adding a spacing between card when using Alphabet List Scroll View

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a page with shows all the users from my app, in this page I have used a dependenci with uses alphabetic scroll view. Althought when I try to set a spacing between card, it won't work.

This is how it is looking:
[image]
This is my screen:

```
import 'package:alphabet_list_scroll_view/alphabet_list_scroll_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/common/custom_drawer/custom_drawer.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/admin_orders_manager.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/admin_users_manager.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/page_manager.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AdminUsersScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: CustomDrawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Usuários',
            style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Consumer<AdminUsersManager>(
          builder: (_, adminUsersManager, __) {
            return AlphabetListScrollView(
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    elevation: 3,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            adminUsersManager.users[index].name!,
                            style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(),
                          ),
                          Text(adminUsersManager.users[index].email!,
                              style: GoogleFonts.firaCode()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ));
              },
              highlightTextStyle: GoogleFonts.firaCode(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 20,
              )),
              indexedHeight: (index) => 60,
              strList: adminUsersManager.names,
              showPreview: true,
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

This is the dependecie:
https://pub.dev/packages/alphabet_list_scroll_view

[image]

Comment: There is no space in your code

Comment: Try `margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),` instead

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj It returned a overlfow,

Comment: You have to adjust something else then

Comment: It seems that the cart height is giving me problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const itemMargin = EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16);
return AlphabetListScrollView(
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Card(
                        margin: itemMargin,
                        elevation: 3,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                adminUsersManager.users[index].name!,
                                style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(),
                              ),
                              Text(adminUsersManager.users[index].email!,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.firaCode()),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ));
                  },
                  highlightTextStyle: GoogleFonts.firaCode(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  )),
                  indexedHeight: (index) => 60 + itemMargin.vertical,
                  strList: adminUsersManager.names,
                  showPreview: true,
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the Container instead of Card, you can replace this code i hope the ui you have designed will be same.

```
  Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 4, spreadRadius: 8)],borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    adminUsersManager.users[index].name!,
                    style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(),
                  ),
                  Text(adminUsersManager.users[index].email!, style: GoogleFonts.firaCode()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this.

1. Try using mediaquery if you think your app is going to be used on multiple devices.
2. Use some paddings.
3. Wrap your Card inside a container and set size to it.